# Adding glow around the text when pressed

Tags: android

Is there any way to add a glow effect to the text when it is pressed. Can we do this by using selector for the text?

Comment: Selectors can help you. Here is an example for glow effect http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml file name editbox_bg.xml in drawable folder.
write the following code in editbox_bg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_focus_yellow" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/editbox_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

editbox_background_focus_yellow is an image. Like this:--->[image]

Now set the background of EditText by @drawable/editbox_bg in your xml file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But the kind of glow i want is like this [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/UJM4P.png